# How to transform a image that is suited for laptop monitor to the image that is to be displayed on a planetarium dome in real time?

Tags: image-processing

Sample image and its required transform are as follows:-

[Example Transform 1](http://i.imgur.com/FVdwG8q)
[Example Transform 2](http://i.imgur.com/313m86q)

How to minimize the number of operations on the input image matrix so as to show a video
from laptop on the planetarium dome in real time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing sometimes back. The steps involved are:

1. Choose an origin in the original image
2. Switch to polar coordinates
3. for every pixel in the original image do interpolation (i had used bilinear)

   You will get the final image after all the interpolation is done. You may need to normalize the image between 0 and 255 for proper visualization

You can also refer to the answer of a similar question that i had posted in SO sometimes back: [creating image using polar coordinates (image transformations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404013/creating-image-using-polar-coordinates-image-transformations)